# Display Woocommerce Related Products by current Category and tags

Tags: woocommerce

Please don't judge this question harshly.

I have tried showing in Related Products only products from the same category in which the user is viewing the product right now, and by product tags (if applicable). But nothing has changed for me.

It turns out that WooCommerce already displays recommended products from the same category and by the same tags by default.

Below you will find the answer to this question. But let this code remain here simply as a sample code.

```
function related_products_by_current_category( $related_posts, $product, $args ) {
    
    global $post;
    
    $cat = $product->get_category_ids();
    $tags = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, "product_tag" );
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        $tags_array[] .= $tag->term_id;
    }

    $related_posts = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
            'tax_query' => array(
                  
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => $cat
                    )
                    array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => $tags_array
                    )
            )
        ) 
    );
    return $related_posts;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'related_products_by_current_category', 999, 3 );
```

Comment: WooCommerce natively displays related products that are in the same category and tags that is how they are determined see [related products] (https://woocommerce.com/document/related-products-up-sells-and-cross-sells/#section-3) . Apart from that, your code has several bugs, eg the $product variable being passed in is actually the $product_id hence get_category_ids wont work. Also you are returning a WP_Query and the return should actually be an array of product_ids, also you are missing a comma after the tax_query array. I hope this helps

Comment: @jtowell Thanks for the clarification. Do you think I should now delete this question or leave this thread as it is?

Comment: I'm not sure, you could accept my comment, and the other person who has said the same as me as an answer, in order to award us both. That way any person with the same question in the future will get the immediate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce already fetches related products based on the same terms( categories and tags )

If you want to get more control over the related products by categories and tags, you can use these two filters

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_related_product_cat_terms', wc_get_product_term_ids( $product_id, 'product_cat' ), $product_id );

apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_related_product_tag_terms', wc_get_product_term_ids( $product_id, 'product_tag' ), $product_id );
```

These filters return the current product categories | tags IDs which will be used to get related products. you can use these filters to return specific terms IDs based on the given product ID .